# PHP string to integer not playing nice, encoding issue?

Tags: php, casting, integer

I am reading in a CSV file (in UTF-8 encoding). One of the values is a number and when I try to cast it as an integer so I can do some calculations it is just being set to zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
var_dump ( $row3[_MM_Impressions] );
//writes: string(5) "59"

$imps = (int)$row3[_MM_Impressions];
var_dump($imps);
//writes: int(0) 

$imps = $row3[_MM_Impressions]*1;
var_dump($imps);
//writes: int(0) 

$imps = intval($row3[_MM_Impressions]);
var_dump($imps);
//writes: int(0)
```

Comment: Do you know what the other 3 characters in the string are?

Comment: var_dump : string(5) : '59' doesn't look right to me either

Comment: %00%35%00%39%00 (this is the hex dump).

Comment: What is the true value $row3[__MM_Impressions] ?

Comment: Try removing the null bytes `preg_replace("/\x00/", "" , $row3[_MM_Impressions])`

Comment: It seems to cause a problem. $imps = preg_replace("/\x00/", "" , $row3[_MM_Impressions]);       var_dump ( $imps ); results in "NULL"

Answer (score 2):

You have HEX string number in your vars... so why don't you use [hexdec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hexdec.php)?

> Returns the decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal number represented
>   by the hex_string argument. hexdec() converts a hexadecimal string to
>   a decimal number.
>
> hexdec() will ignore any non-hexadecimal characters it encounters.

Comment: Unfortunately it gets the wrong int number though. Vardump (original): string(5) "59"            Vardump (after hexdec ($row3[_MM_Impressions])): int(89) int(89)      here is another example that should be 49 as an int: string(5) "49" int(73) int(73)